# How to use Basic Authentication to access Asp.Net MVC 4 Intranet Web API method which uses Windows Authentication from a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, basic-authentication, asp.net-web-api

Here is some background!

I developed a small Asp.Net MVC 4 intranet site using the default Intranet template and am using `Windows Authentication`. I also added a `Web Api Controller` and wrote some REST service methods in it which I access using JQuery from the site's page. The `Web.Config` contains the following:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

The site is works fine and it requires the user to provide their `Windows Credentials` in order to access the site.

**Issue**

I also am developing a windows service which will run on another computer on the network and will access one of the `Windows API controller`'s action which I created in previous step. Now the issue is that I cannot provide `Windows Credentials` to the RESTful API method from within the Windows service... as no user might use that system ... i hope u get what i mean:

**What have I tried**

1. Allowed `Anonymous Authentication` to `True` in Web project's properties. Then used `AllowAnonymous` attribute over the web api method. Did not work.
2. I though why not create another `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` which will only be applied to the API methods which are to be accessed from the Window Service. This way the new functionality will override the existing `Windows Authentication` functionality and I would be able to provide username/password of my choice for BASIC authentication which will only be used from the Windows Service. So I created the a new `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` class by taking help from [Rick Strahl's blog](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter).

   ```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [AuthorizeCallFromWindowsService]    
   public IssueResponse CloseEmployeeLicenses(int userID)
   {
       return null;
   }
   ```

Again, this did not work. The API method requires same Windows authentication credentials and I want to use custom hard coded username/password.

What would you propose? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario and I decided to create a new user type in our application called Service User. We created a service account in the domain and when we installed the windows service on the server (which was in the same network) we forced the windows service to run as the service account (with network domain\username and password). We have actually created 3 service accounts in our application, one for each environment: ServiceAccountDev, ServiceAccountUAT and ServiceAccountPROD and disabled/enabled each account as appropriate.